# LWC Show datable depending on the "li key" parametr

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have an HTML structure:

```
 <li key={element} class="slds-item">
  <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={data} columns={columns}></lightning-datatable>
  </li>
```

and an APEX controller with method:

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static List<PDM_Voucher__c> getVoucherList(String id) {
        return [SELECT Id,Key__c,Date_Of_Deadline__c,Employee__c,Purchase_Office__c,Order__c FROM PDM_Voucher__c WHERE Order__c = :id] ;}
```

I want to show data-table with different data which one depends on element.id . I have an idea to invoke the js method which one takes the element.id, invoke getVoucherList(element.id) and connect it to 'data' parameter in data-table. But I don't know how to do it, any idea? Or another solution?

Comment: To simplify: I want to have data-table with different values on each <li> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't do that; you'd have the data for each wrapped up in the element. Here's a modification:

```
 <li key={element.id} class="slds-item">
  <lightning-datatable key-field="id" data={element.data} columns={columns}></lightning-datatable>
  </li>
```

Notice how I can reuse the columns attribute (assuming they're all the same), but the data is part of the wrapper/data structure. This would be the standard way of doing this.

Comment: So I should place my li body in another component?

Comment: @KamilMotyka No, that's not necessary. Just change your data structure a bit.

Comment: okay, what if data-table is not the only element in Li ?

Comment: @KamilMotyka It should work.

Comment: look, I have li list. Each element has data from the element object and should have a data-table with data from apex controller which one depends on element object id. How i can pass that data to data table ?s

Comment: Element does not contains data which one i Need but that data depend on element id